# Java: Casting Object to Array type

Tags: java

I am using a web service that returns a plain object of the type "Object". Debug shows clearly that there is some sort of Array in this object so I was wondering how I can cast this "Object" to an Array (or similar)?

I tried the following:

```
Collection<String> arr = (Collection<String>) values;
Vector<String> arr = (Vector<String>) values;
ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>) values;
```

But nothing worked. I always get an InvocationTargetException.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

Sadly, I had to remove the link to the image that showed the output of Eclipse's debugger because it was no longer available. Please do not wonder why in the answers an image is mentioned that is not there anymore.

Comment: InvocationTargetException contains another Exception. What does it say?

Comment: Eclipse says ClassCastException.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your `values` object is obviously an `Object[]` containing a `String[]` containing the values.

```
String[] stringValues = (String[])values[0];
```

Answer (score 26):

What you've got (according to the debug image) is an object array containing a string array. So you need something like:

```
Object[] objects = (Object[]) values;
String[] strings = (String[]) objects[0];
```

You haven't shown the type of `values` - if this is already `Object[]` then you could just use `(String[])values[0]`.

Of course even with the cast to `Object[]` you could still do it in one statement, but it's ugly:

```
String[] strings = (String[]) ((Object[])values)[0];
```