# How to access elements of an array which is referenced by an element of object array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Main {

  int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3};
  int[] arr2 = {7, 8, 9};

  Object[] refarr = {arr1, arr2};

  System.out.println("Print 2 from arr1 without typing arr1 in a single line.");
}
```

I tried `(refarr[0])[1]` but it didn't work.

Comment: `int[][] refarr`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611735/java-casting-object-to-array-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `refarr[0]` to `int[]` since it's an `Object` according to refarr's declaration. Then you can use it as an `int[]`.

[Try it like this:](https://ideone.com/GvT0db)

```
((int[])refarr[0])[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

refarr is an array of objects, aka arr1 and arr2 are Objects and not int[] types inside that construction, so you need to cast: `((int[])refarr[0])[1]`